# Can WPF trigger values persist beyond the trigger condition?

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with WPF triggers. In my application i used a multitrigger but would like to achieve that changes made when a trigger's conditions become true to persist and NOT to be invalidated when the trigger's conditions become false AGAIN.
Is it possible to realize what I want ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and left out a word. So here's the question again:

In my application i used a multitrigger but would like to achieve that changes made when a trigger's conditions become true to persist and NOT to be invalidated when the trigger's conditions become false AGAIN. Is it possible to realize what I want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers don't have any memory:  As soon as the trigger becomes inapplicable the trigger's setters are unapplied.  You want a condition that "locks on" once it has been set.  This can be done with a very simple and generic piece of code.

First you need an attached property that you can "lock on".  Here's a simple class with a "IsLocked" attached property that becomes true whenever the "DoLock" property is set and stays that way from then on:

```
public class LockingProperty : DependencyObject
{
  // IsLocked
  public static bool GetIsLocked(DependencyObject obj) { return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsLockedProperty); }
  public static void SetIsLocked(DependencyObject obj, bool value) { obj.SetValue(IsLockedProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLockedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsLocked", typeof(bool), typeof(LockingProperty));

  // DoLock
  public static bool GetDoLock(DependencyObject obj) { return (bool)obj.GetValue(DoLockProperty); }
  public static void SetDoLock(DependencyObject obj, bool value) { obj.SetValue(DoLockProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DoLockProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoLock", typeof(bool), typeof(LockingProperty), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) => { SetIsLocked(obj, true); }
  });
}
```

Now you can emulate a locking trigger using two separate triggers:

```
<Triggers>
  <Trigger ... your trigger conditions here ...>
    <Setter Property="my:LockingProperty.DoLock" Value="true" />
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="my:LockingProperty.IsLocked" Value="true" />
    ... your setters here ...
  </Trigger>
</Triggers>
```

Note that the first trigger in this example can be a Trigger, DataTrigger, MultiTrigger or MultiDataTrigger - whatever you need to express your triggering condition.

Comment: Hi Ray and thanks for your answer. I really like it and it seems to me that it really does what I wanted however I realized that for my needs it is better to implement the logic what has to be done in a ViewModel class instead of in XAML and bind to it. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it might be helpful in the future.

Comment: Yes, implemeting such behavior in the ViewModel is often better than doing it with triggers.  The thing I like about WPF is that it has so much flexibility.  Very few other technologies have the power to create such a "locking trigger" feature, or to really handle ViewModels for that matter.  So no matter how you implement your solution you win.